# opening a .txt file with php (read / write) and deleting the old content and replacing it with a new one

Tags: php

I want to change the old values of a text file with a new values (delete the old content and replace it), when I use the code below it shows me an error page , don't really know how to fix this , even used the different types of file opening methods (w , r+ , a ...) and didn't work !

```
$i=$_POST['id'];
$fp = fopen ("/test/member_dl.txt", "r+");  
$ch = fgets ($fp);

$t=explode('||',$ch);
$t[$i-1]='';
$ch2=implode('||',$t);
fwrite($fp,$ch2);
fclose ($fp);
```

Comment: look for PHP fopen() mode, look for what r+/w/w+ mode does. Might be of help

Comment: silly as it may sound, check the file permissions. again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst it's open as `$fp = fopen ("/test/member_dl.txt", "r+");`

You will not be able to `fwrite($fp,$ch2);`

Opening it with 'w+' should enable read and writing.

Try this:

```
$i=$_POST['id'];
$fp = fopen("/test/member_dl.txt", "w+");
$ch = fread($fp, filesize($fp));

$t=explode('||',$ch);
$t[$i-1]='';
$ch2=implode('||',$t);
fwrite($fp,$ch2);
fclose ($fp);
```

**EDIT:**

Tested this, this works

```
$ch = file_get_contents("test.txt");

$t=explode('||',$ch);
$t[$i-1]='';
$ch2=implode('||',$t);

file_put_contents("test.txt","hello");
```

Comment: still not working , i used your code and still showing that the .txt file conetent didn't change :(

Answer (score 1):

As you want to completely replace the contents, why not just delte it, and re-create it?

```
unlink ("/test/member_dl.txt"); 
$fp = fopen ("/test/member_dl.txt", "r+"); 
// Continue with your code.
// Not sure I follow what you are doing with it
```

Edit: I am not sure I understand what that part of your code is doing to be honest.

The `unlink()` command deletes the file. From there you can start over and write the file out as you need it?

Comment: i tried this but it shows an error , can you please write me all the code so i try because maybe i misunderstand what you mean!