# Have my php script not run when I access the URL, but rather at scheduled times via Cron Job

Tags: php, cron, bluehost

Others have asked similar questions, but from what I understand their scripts are automated, but when you go to `www.mydomain.com/myscript.php`, the script still runs.

Or at least that's how it was for me when I set up a cron job in the cpanel for my script. Is there any way I can make it so the script doesn't run when I access that URL, but rather is static, except for its scheduled updates?

I've seen solutions where the script itself is edited to check the last time it ran, and if it was less than X hours ago, it presents that log file. 
The problem is I don't know where to find that log file. I'm using BlueHost, if that matters.

Comment: there is no standard "log file" to say when a script was last run. that's something the script itself would have to create/maintain. but why have one script do it all? have the actual job somewhere outside of your document root (cron won't care) to do the job, then something in your webroot that simply presents the results of whatever the last run was. keeping the main job script outside the doc root completely prevents it being executed by hitting a url.

Comment: Ahh I see. The problem is my web experience is limited, as well as my php. Can you recommend any tutorial or something? Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The main thing Marc is saying is that you should put the script outside of the webroot. Programming knowledge isn't needed for that, only cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

You could add something like `if ($argv[1] == 'RUN')` at the top of your php script (before it starts executing your stuff).

Then you just need to pass that parameter in your cron command, i.e.: `4 4 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/mydomain.com/myscript.php RUN` to run at 04:04 every day (n.b. easy webtool to check your cron statement is correct - http://cronchecker.net/)

This way, you can keep your script where it is, but it won't execute when you browse to it.

Comment: Ahhh, got it. Clever. I'll give that a try.

Comment: But then in my app when I pull data from that URL, the URL will be blank, won't it? I need it to present JSON.

Comment: Then you'll need to put the codeblock that's responsible for providing the data outside the if statement :-)

Comment: How exactly would I do that, give the most recent version of it? My PHP skills are limited at best.

Comment: It's hard to say because I don't know what your script looks like. But if you would put the update part (as in, the thing you *only* want to be executed when the cronjob calls the script) in a separate function `execute_update_things`, you could put `if ($argv[1] == 'RUN') execute_update_things();` at the top of your script.

Comment: What I do with the script is scrape data from a webpage. I then take that and encode it as JSON. So what I would need to do is present the latest version of that JSON outside of the IF function. I'm just not sure how I would get a copy of it from the last time it ran.

Comment: Do you have experience with any storage stuff? Some basic options are putting it in a temporary file, or in a database like MySQL. For the first, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738321/opening-a-txt-file-with-php-read-write-and-deleting-the-old-content-and-rep . For the second, check http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Comment: Thanks! I wrote it to a .json file, and when the URL is loaded, I'll just display that file!

Comment: Hey, for some reason when I pass RUN on the command line, the if function "if ($argv[1] == 'RUN')" still isn't being met, and it moves on. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: Don't know, but I did found that it throws a notice if you don't pass any args. With this file: `<?php if (count($argv) > 1 && $argv[1] == 'RUN') { echo "yep\n"; } else { echo "nope\n"; } ?>`, I get the following responses: `$ php test.php RUN >>> yep` - `$ php test.php >>> nope`